# How do I change an application icon on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, icons

Specifically, I want to swap out the Chrome icon for that of Chromium, as I find the former garish.

Answer (score 7):

If the icon is newly created or downloaded, and does not already exist in the `icons` directory, its suite of images at different dimensions will need to be placed in the respective subdirectories, eg:

```
cp chromium-browser.png ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/
```

Then to make the application reference the new icon, copy the relevant `.desktop` configuration file into your user directory structure if it's not already there:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

Edit the `.desktop` file Icon property to reference the new name (without any suffixes):

```
Icon=chromium-browser
```

All references to the application throughout the desktop should now appear with the new icon.

Comment: I'd certainly appreciate anyone improving my terminology here.

Answer (score 0):

The magic, high priority, local location, if the icon is missing, is, `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/`. Or theme-specific, `~/.local/share/icons/<THEME_NAME>/scalable/apps/`

So, you look up the icons in `/usr/share/icons/` with some thumbnail previewer, like Nautilus, or image manager, like Gwenview.

```sh
xdg-open /usr/share/icons
```

Then, copy the file and rename to `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/<ICON_NAME>.*`. Note that the icon extension doesn't matter. It can be SVG or PNG.

You can look up the icon name in the `*.desktop` file.

```sh
# To find the location of the appropriate desktop file

find /usr/share/applications -iname '*chrome.desktop'
find ~/.local/share/applications -iname '*chrome.desktop'
```

I wouldn't edit `*.desktop` file, especially for non-local location, as it will overwritten by `apt-get update`.